# Apache 2.2 with mod_jk / Tomcat 6.0 / Removing context paths with 2 wars

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm currently using a unique server to host 2 Java EE applications.
The server is a Linux Debian 6, with Apache 2 and Tomcat 6.
I'm using mod_jk in order to remove port from url.

Until now, those applications are available on url http://myserver/app1 and http://myserver/app2

I've got some new dns and I want to access to those application with url like http://dnsname1/ and http://dnsname2/

The Apache 2 setup with Named virtual hosts is succesfull and http://dnsname1/ answered well. I need to add the context to reach the application, like http://dnsname1/app1.

But I want to reach the application without adding the context path, like http://dnsname1/

Here is the apache2 virtual hosts config:

```
NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
ServerName myserver

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName dnsname1
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.fr

    DocumentRoot /app1/www

    ErrorLog /app1/logs/app1_errors.log
    CustomLog /app1/logs/app1_access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    JkMount /app1 ajp13
    JkMount /app1* ajp13
    JkLogFile /app1/logs/app1-mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel debug
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName dnsname2
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.fr

    DocumentRoot /app2/www

    ErrorLog /app2/logs/app2_errors.log
    CustomLog /app2/logs/app2_access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    JkMount /app2 ajp13
    JkMount /app2* ajp13
    JkLogFile /app2/logs/app2-mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel debug
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
</VirtualHost>
```

Somebody could tell me how to set up my virtual host?